# Why is no 3rd marker being created on map?

Tags: javascript

I have the below JS code

A map renders just fine and when clicking the 1st click on the map, it creates and pins a marker on the place it was clicked. The 2nd time I click, it creates a 2nd marker and pins to the position that was clicked. Great!
However, when clicking the 3rd time, it doesn't create another marker! It instead moves the 2nd marker to the position of the 3rd click! Why is it doing that? It's supposed to create a 3rd marker, but for some reason, it moves the 2nd marker to a new position which should not be the case.

[image: map]

The marker is inside the  tags too `<Marker key={i} position={latLng}` so it should work properly...
It seems that `{props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={props.markerPosition} />}` is not creating a new instance for the marker after the 2nd marker is created for some reason...

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withStateHandlers } from "recompose";
import { InfoWindow, withGoogleMap, withScriptjs, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

const Map = compose(
    withStateHandlers(() => ({
        isMarkerShown: false,
        markerPosition: null
      }), {
        onMapClick: ({ isMarkerShown }) => (e) => ({
            markerPosition: e.latLng,
            isMarkerShown:true
        })
      }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)
    (props =>
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
            onClick={props.onMapClick}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={props.markerPosition} />}

        </GoogleMap>
    )

export default class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                <Map
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=VALIDAPIKEY"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                />
                {clicks.map((latLng, i) => (
                    <Marker key={i} position={latLng} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map

Comment: I don't see anywhere you define `clicks` in your code snippet

Comment: @NickVu oh you mean like this `const [clicks, setClicks] = React.useState([]);`

Comment: Could I know where you call `setClicks`? That's the main part for understanding you set your markers properly or not

Comment: @NickVu It doesnt look like I have it defined anywhere actually...then i wonder how i was able to click and place 2 markers...

Comment: Hmm that's too weird though. I think you need to find where the root of that variable is

Comment: @NickVu looked throughout every file but couldn't locate its definition anywhere. Could this be the problem? Although the map launches fine and 2 markers get placed too...interesting...

Comment: Could you check `window.clicks` on `console.log`? it may be declared internally by that library and you just use it

Comment: @NickVu where would console.log be?

Comment: open your browser and F12